# If checkbox selected make input required

Tags: javascript, validation, input, checkbox

As part of a web form, I have two checkboxes (both with the name "my_checkbox") and two input filelds (one with the name "input1" and the other named "input2").

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" value="some text" onclick="a function;    checkBoxValidate(0);">

<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" value="some diffrent text" onclick="a diffrent function; checkBoxValidate(1);">

<input id="input1" name="input1"  />

<input id="input2" name="input2"  />
```

If user selects the first checkbox, input1 must not be empty. If user selects the second checkbox, input2 must not be empty. The two checkboxes must have the same name. Function checkBoxValidate assures the two checkboxes cannot be selected at the same time (I don't like radio buttons).

My javascript:

```
}else if (!document.myform.my_checkbox[0].checked && myform.input1.value == ''){ 
alert ('Please enter some text!',function(){$(myform.input1).focus();}); 
return false;

}else if (!document.myform.my_checkbox[1].checked && myform.input2.value == ''){ 
alert ('Please enter some text!',function(){$(myform.input2).focus();}); 
return false;
```

Of course, nothing works! Please help? :)

Comment: what do you mean by the **two checkboxes cannot be selected at the same time**?

Comment: post all of your js function, not only small part

Comment: The alert() method displays an alert dialog with the optional specified content and an OK button. I didn't find any callback method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert

Comment: Also post more of your HTML, particularly the containing form, but more if it's relevant.

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question. To make things easier: I want a text input field validated (must not be empty) only if the user secects a particular checkbox.

<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox">

<input id="input1" name="input1"  />

If "my_checkbox" selected, alert that "input1" must not be empty.

Nothing I found so far works for my form...

Comment: "I do not like radio buttons" - that is plain silly. you want radio button functionality, use radio buttons

Comment: use a hidden input element and make the checkboxes purely for interface.  update hidden element with proper value and use that for submit.  However, everybody who has ever filled out a form will expect a radio button.

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question. To make things easier: I want a text input field validated (must not be empty) only if the user secects a particular checkbox.

<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox">

<input id="input1" name="input1"  />

If "my_checkbox" selected, alert that "input1" must not be empty.

Nothing I found so far works for my form...

Comment: why do you have two checkboxes with same name then?  sounds like you just need one to represent two states since it's either checked (validated needed) or unchecked (no validation needed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing you might want to take this simple, I write it simple and use plain JS since you did not tag the question with jQuery.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5fT89/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var form1=document.getElementById("form1"); // assuming <form id="form1"
  form1.onsubmit=function() {
    if (this.my_checkbox[0].checked && this.input1.value=="") {
      alert("Please enter something in input 1");
      this.input1.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if (this.my_checkbox[1].checked && this.input2.value=="") {
      alert("Please enter something in input 2");
      this.input2.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
  // if the checkboxes had different IDs this could have been one function
  form1.my_checkbox[0].onclick=function() {
    this.form.my_checkbox[1].checked=!this.checked;
  }
  form1.my_checkbox[1].onclick=function() {
    this.form.my_checkbox[0].checked=!this.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked, after I did some minor changes to adapt to my actual code! And sorry if the question was not well documented...

Answer (score 2):

**HMTL**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="CB1"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox12"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#checkbox1').on('click',function(){
   var checked=$(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked==true)
    {   
        $('#textbox1').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#checkbox12').attr('checked', false);
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled',false);
        var text=$('#textbox').val();
        checktext(text)
    }
  });

$('#checkbox12').on('click',function(){
   var checked=$(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked==true)
    {   
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#checkbox1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#textbox1').attr('disabled',false);
        var text=$('#textbox1').val();
        checktext(text)
    }
  });

function checktext(text){
    alert(text);
    if(text=='')
        alert('Enter Text');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ptqPW/11/)

Comment: var checked=$('#checkbox1').is(':checked'); ? Why not $(this).is(":checked") - and where is the validation on submit? And use .prop instead of attr. Lastly, the question was not tagges jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the **this** in the checkbox and i never disabled the checkbox i disabled the **textbox**

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I thought you did :)