# How to make a flask form section required if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, python, flask

If the user checks a checkbox I want the form section to be required, but if the checkbox is not checked then it is not required to submit the form. Rough example, but the goal is if they check they have played baseball they cant submit the form until they type how many years they have played.

sports.py

```
 @app.route("/sports", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def sports():
        form = SportsForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash(f'Thanks!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('sports'))
        return render_template('sports.html', title='sports', form=form)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange

class Sports(FlaskForm):
    baseball = IntegerField('How many years', NumberRange(min=0, max=20)])
    soccer = StringField('How many years', NumberRange(min=0, max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

sports.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">What sports have you played?</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="baseball_check">
                <label for="baseball_check">Baseball</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.baseball.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.baseball(size=20) }}
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="soccer_check">
                <label for="soccer_check">Soccer</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.soccer.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.soccer(size=20) }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
                 <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you created any JavaScript code that reacts on the checkbox? If yes, can you please post it? Generally speaking, you need to set the ```required``` attribute of the [input field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Comment: I've tried a variation of this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409536/javascript-htmlmake-input-fields-required-on-checkbox-check) but I cant seem to make it work with the python flask form input fields.